# Eshell simple echo in parenthesis not working

Tags: eshell, bash, subprocess

Why doesn't the following work in eshell

```
$ (echo "foo")
Symbol's function definition is void: echo
```

What I tried:
googled eshell parenthesis not working

More Context:
    Eventually I'm trying to run `(source functions.sh; myCoolFunc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You incorrectly assumed that `eshell` starts your default shell
specified in `/etc/passwd` but it doesn't, it's [a shell on its
own](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html):

> Eshell is a shell-like command interpreter implemented in Emacs Lisp.
>   It invokes no external processes except for those requested by the
>   user. It is intended to be an alternative to the IELM (see Emacs Lisp
>   Interaction) REPL for Emacs and with an interface similar to command
>   shells such as bash, zsh, rc, or 4dos.

The `source` command you want to run does not work with `bash` files
in `eshell` as you would expect it but with `eshell` commands as help
mentions:

```
~ $ source -h
usage: source FILE [ARGS]
Invoke the Eshell commands in FILE in a subshell, binding ARGS to $1,
$2, etc.

    -h, --help           show this usage screen
```

In order to achieve what you want in `eshell` buffer you need to start
`bash` manually:

<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> eshell

```
~ $ bash
$ (echo hi)
hi
```

Comment: if I''m starting bash manually like you suggested, am I better off simple using M-x shell  instead?

Comment: Probably yes if you are not interested in using `eshell` at all.

Comment: @joshsverns: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: very subtle Ark!